# How to find charts (graphs) in powerpoint using vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I just want the code or property to find chart in the powerpoint silde using macro(vba).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to find chart is

```
Sub EachSlides()
'developer by Bruno Leite  
'http://officevb.com  
Dim sld As Slide
Dim i As Integer

   For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
           For i = 1 To sld.Shapes.Placeholders.Count
                      'select the placeholder
                      sld.Shapes.Placeholders(i).Select msoCTrue
           Next i
   Next sld

End Sub
```

Comment: Does that code actually do you any good?  I can't see how it would, but if so, great.  If not, mention which version(s) of PPT you need to support; identifying charts is a little different from one version to another.  And do you need to identify just charts the user has inserted using the usual Insert, Chart command or also charts that are copy/pasted from Excel?